# Find the expectation of $Z=min\{X,Y\}$ which $X~N(\mu,{\sigma}^2)$,$Y~N(\mu,{\sigma}^2)$

Tags: normal-distribution, expectation, order-statistics

Find the expectation of $Z=min\{X,Y\}$ which $X\sim N(\mu,{\sigma}^2)$,$Y\sim N(\mu,{\sigma}^2)$. $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables.

This is how far I go:
According to order statistics, I know that $PDF$ of $Z$ is:$$f_Z(z)=2(1-F(z))f(z)$$

where $f(z)$ is the $PDF$ of $X$ or $Y$ and $F(z)$ is the anti-derivative(CDF) of $f(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}$exp$\left(-\frac{(z-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$

So $$E(Z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}zf_Z(z)dz=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}2(1-F(z))f(z)dz=2E(Z)-2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}zf(z)F(z)dz=2\mu-2A$$

I stuck in solving $A$, any help in solving $A$ or the original problem would be appreciated. Thanks

$\color{red}{Edit}$ [By following Did's comment]

Let $Z=\mu+\sigma Z_0$
where $Z_0$ coresponds to the standard normal distribution. Then my original $$E(Z)=u+min\{Z_1,Z_2\}=\mu+\sigma(2\mu-2A)=\mu+0-2\sigma A$$
$$A=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}z\varphi(z)\Phi(z)dz=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varphi^2(z)dz=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-z^2}dz=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sqrt{\pi}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}$$
So $\color{red}{E(Z)=\mu-2\sigma A=\mu-\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt\pi}}$

Comment: First, $Z=\mu+\sigma Z_0$ where $Z_0$ coresponds to the standard normal distribution ($\mu=0$, $\sigma^2=1$) with PDF $\varphi$ and CDF $\Phi$. Second, $z\varphi(z)=-\varphi'(z)$ and $\Phi'(z)=\varphi(z)$ hence an integration by parts yields $$\int_\mathbb Rz\varphi(z)\Phi(z)dz=\int_\mathbb R\varphi^2(z)dz=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\mathbb R\varphi(\sqrt{2}z)dz=\ldots$$

Comment: @Did Maybe my notation mislead you that $\Phi$ is the CDF of standard normal distribution. But it's not in my question. I'd better edit my question properly.

Comment: @Did I get your idea. With $Z=\mu+\sigma Z_0$ I can transform the question into $Z=min(X,Y) \sim Z=min(\mu+\sigma Z_0)=\mu+\sigma min(X,Y)$. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which antiderivative of $f$ is $F$?

Comment: @Ian I edit my question to make it clear.

Comment: That didn't clarify anything. I asked which antiderivative of $f$ is $F$; I already know what $f$ is. But which antiderivative are you using? Ordinarily it would be $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(z) dz$, which is the CDF of your nonstandard normal. Anyway, Did transformed your variable so that you could work with the standard normal instead of the nonstandard normal you started with, thus $\varphi$ and $\Phi$ in his comment indeed come from the standard normal.

Comment: @Ian I thought that when one use $\Phi(z)$, it means it's the CDF of $\color{red}{standard}$ normal distribution. So I make this clear and does it really matter to determine which constant do I use when  doing infinite integration?

Comment: First, yes, it does matter which constant (or equivalently, which lower limit) you pick if you use it in another calculation, as you are doing here. Second, yes, $\Phi$ is from the standard normal. But this is the point of the transformation at the start: we turn $X$ and $Y$ into $\mu+\sigma Z_1$ and $\mu + \sigma Z_2$ where $Z_1,Z_2$ are iid standard normals. Then $E[\min \{ X,Y \}]=E[ \min \{ \mu+\sigma Z_1,\mu+\sigma Z_2 \}]=\mu+\sigma E[\min \{ Z_1,Z_2 \}]$. (Here I have used that $\sigma>0$.)

Comment: @Ian I have no idea which constant to choose. . .

Comment: I'm pretty sure that what is intended is that $F$ is the CDF of $X$, as I suggested before. But I haven't seen this "order statistic" formula before, which is why I asked you.

Comment: @Ian Yes. That's what I mean. It's a uncertain limit integral.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "uncertain limit integral"; we seem to be talking past each other. My point is that you can't uniquely identify $F$ by saying "$F$ is the antiderivative of $f$". $F$ is *some* antiderivative of $f$, and in this case I am pretty sure that it is the one which vanishes at $-\infty$, i.e. $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(y) dy$.

Comment: @Ian You are correct. I should have clarified this clearly in my question. I am sorry.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1804353/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We exploit the formula

$$\min \{ X,Y \}=X-\min \{ X-Y,0 \}.$$

Hence $E[\min \{ X,Y \}]=E[X]-E[\min \{ X-Y,0 \}]=\mu-E[\min \{ X-Y,0 \}]$.

It remains to compute the second term. Since $X,Y$ are iid $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, $X-Y$ is $N(0,2 \sigma^2)$. So the second term is

$$\int_{-\infty}^0 0 dz + \int_0^\infty z n_{0,2\sigma^2}(z) dz$$

where $n_{m,s^2}$ represents the pdf of a $N(m,s^2)$ variable. This last integral can be explicitly calculated to be $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{\pi}}$. So the overall answer is $\mu-\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{\pi}}$.

This approach was suggested in Mark Joshi's answer but the OP expressed that they didn't follow that answer, so I filled in some details.

Comment: I calculated $E[\min \{ X-Y,0 \}]$ and it's correct. But in $\int_{-\infty}^0 0 dx$ , I don't understand why the range of integral is $(-\infty,0)$ and why you use the letter $x$(Can I use another letter, for example, $t$). I know this term should be zero, but how can we determine the range of the integral.

Comment: @Rowan Let $Z=X-Y$ (in my notation). When $Z \leq 0$, $\min \{ Z,0 \}=0$. When $Z > 0$, $\min \{ Z,0 \}=Z$. I've just split the integral between these two cases (and simplified $0 n_{0,2\sigma^2}(z)$ to just $0$). As for the variable of integration, it really doesn't matter; I've changed it to $z$ for consistency's sake.

Answer (score 1):

you can view the whole as an option pricing problem. 
$$
\min(X,Y) = X - (X-Y)_+
$$
So what is 
$$
E((X-Y)_+) 
$$
?

$X-Y$ is distributed $N(0,2\sigma^2).$ Write it as $X-Y = \sigma \sqrt{2} Z$ with $Z$ standard normal, then
$$
E((X-Y)_+) = \sqrt{2} \sigma E(Z_+).
$$
Now
$$
E(Z_+) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int \limits_{0}^{\infty} z e^{-z^2/2}dz = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} .
$$
Done.

For more info look up the Bachelier model. (see eg my book More Mathematical Finance.)

Comment: I'm not sure what the finance commentary contributes here, given its brevity and the fact that the question has no obvious financial context. Also, you've technically assumed $\sigma^2=1$ (though this is of course easily fixed).

Comment: dropping the sigma was a typo. the finance commentary contributes the fact that there's a huge literature on this sort of problem if you know where to look.

Comment: Mark, Maybe My notation $\Phi$ mislead you that $\Phi$ is  the CDF of standard normal distribution. Actually, it's not and your answer is not the same with the answer given by my teacher.($\mu-\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{\pi}})$

Comment: @Rowan When you put it together it's the same: $E[Z_+]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}$ so $\sigma \sqrt{2} E[Z_+]=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{\pi}}$. Then plug that in and you get your answer.

Comment: @Ian Actually, I don't quite understand this answer but noticed that the answer is not the same with my teacher's. Anyway, thanks for reminding.